# Как задать рандомное число в JS.Игровой бот . Js циклы

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы программа генерировала случайное число не от 0 до 1, а в любом указанном диапазоне?

```
min = Math.ceil(1);
max = Math.floor(1000);
var number = Math.random();

function getRandomInRange(min, max) {
  while (true) {
    var userNumber = prompt('Введите число');
    if (isNaN(userNumber)) {
      alert('Введите число!');
      continue;
    }
    if (parseInt(userNumber) === number) {
      alert('Верно!');
      break;
    }
    else if (parseInt(userNumber) > number) {
      alert('Больше!');
    }
    else if (parseInt(userNumber) < number) {
      alert('Меньше!');
    }
  }
}

getRandomInRange();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо строки

```
var number = Math.random();
```

вставь

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
```

Должно сработать.